# I lost my eths? Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

Tags: metamask, swaps

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf7c3d12137403f0b6794856fea92bc1665f4fd1c393b665ea0f485f9a5f8f16e

https://coinmarketcap.com/es/currencies/gyen/

Hi, I try to buy GYEN I got this error and they still haven't refunded my money to my wallet, what do I do? I try to do it with metamask btw

Answer (score 1):

The transaction reverted so funds should have been returned immediately. If they didn't then it is a bug in the wallet. Either contact the wallet developers or if you have the seed or private key switch to another wallet.